# SEO : URL structure in magento

Tags: magento, url, seo, sitemap

Currently I have a online store in magento.

I am using the url structure http://sitename/categoryname/productname

if I will change it to http://sitename/productname is this will be helpful to index ?

The main thing is that my site is doing well now but on search unique product page urls are not showing on google search. If I will change it then how it will be impact on site?

How can i do this without any bad impact? Please help..

Comment: [Click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55368/remove-parent-categories-from-subcategory-urls) Check this url and resolve your problem

Comment: thanks Rajesh.. Let me check..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you have Same product in multiple categories. It creates duplicate content issues.

By remove category path from the URL, It will help you to make your products URL unique for all categories.

You can manage this from backend configuration. In backend From top Navigation go to `System` >> `Configuartion` >> `Catalog`.
In `Search Engine Optimizations` Group, Set `No`  to `Use Categories Path for Product URLs`. Reindex `Catalog URL Rewrites`.

Comment: thanks Pankaj.. As now our url had cached by Google.. If I will change, it will make any impact on existing ranking ?